# Google+ Sharing - Passing hashes as parameter

Tags: share, google-plus, hashtag

In twitter, you can tell what hashtags to be included when pressing the tweet button, and that's done using the `hashtags` parameter.

Is there anything similar while sharing to Google+? I've read the [Share documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/share/) but found nothing like that (I care most about the Share Link method of sharing).

Do you know any ways of accomplishing that?

Answer (score 1):

If your main interest is to be able to search your posts by hashtag, you can add hashtags to the snippet description. The hashtag will not be rendered differently from the rest of the text and will not be clickable though.

```
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
  <head>
    <meta itemprop="name" content="Example">
    <meta itemprop="description" content="
        An #example of how to add #hashtags to the snippet description.">
    <meta itemprop="image" 
        content="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="g-plus" data-action="share"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      (function() {
        var po = document.createElement('script');
        po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
        po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
      })();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```